# Is it possible to disable tracking comment-only lines with go test?

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-coverage

I have observed that the coverage report generated by `go test -cover` considers lines that consist of only whitespace and a comment within function bodies as lines to be tracked.

For example, in the screenshot below of an HTML coverage report, you can see that the two lines of purely comments (other than leading whitespace) are marked red, which indicates they are not covered (as opposed to being grey, which indicates the lines are not tracked):

[image: screenshot of not covered comments]

Here is the colour legend:

[image: colour legend]

Here are some sample untracked lines from the same file as the screenshot above (these are inside a `struct` definition):

[image: untracked lines]

This report was generated and viewed in Mozilla Firefox by running

```
$ go test -v -timeout 1m -cover -coverprofile cp.out ./... > report 2>&1
$ go tool cover -html=cp.out
```

Is there any flag that can be passed to `go test` to disable tracking comment-only lines for coverage?

If not, is there any tool available that can automatically update my `cp.out` to remove comment only-lines?

Comment: In that case, I believe the "not covered" indicator is for the branch, and not for the lines. If you covered the branch, it should mark lines correctly

Comment: You are correct, if a branch is covered, then `go test` will show the comment-only lines as covered. However, I do not want this behaviour - I want comment-only lines to not be tracked by `go test` in the coverage report at all, i.e., I do not want comment-only lines to be considered covered or not covered in the coverage report generated by `go test`.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: If that is my only option, that is very unfortunate. My team will not be able to upgrade to Go 1.21, since we support Windows 7, and Go 1.21 will drop Windows 7 support. Though maybe I will be lucky and the Go team will be able to fix my bug in a 1.20 release.

Comment: You can always fork it and create a custom build yourself. But the behavior you described sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Bug filed: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61403